# BillingClient cannot be applied

Tags: android, android-billing

I'm trying to implement in app purchases in my app, there is a nice tutorial from [Google](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_java_kotlin#java) themselves. However, on the first line of code I already get an error message...

When trying to use this code:

```
mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).setListener(this).build();
```

Which I implement as:

```
`mBillingClient=BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build()`
```

I get *error: incompatible types: MyActivity cannot be converted to PurchasesUpdatedListener*

Answer (score 6):

Your `Activity` must implements `PurchasesUpdatedListener` like :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    ...
}
```